# Don't understand an algebraic answer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Question:

$a+\frac{10b}{a^2+b^2} = 5$

$b+\frac{10a}{a^2+b^2} = 4$

Prove $ab$ is not equal to 0.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: if $ab=0$ Then either a or b is zero. Inserting for example $a=0$ in both equations leads to an impossibile system of equations for $b$

Comment: Do we know that the set here is an integral domain? Maybe it's irrelevant, but we can use $ab=0 \Rightarrow a= 0$ or $b=0 $ only when we working in integral domains, Right??

Comment: @Rick Given the level of this question, I think it is safe to assume that we are working with the real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=0$.

Thus, from the first equation we obtain $b=2$ and from the second we obtain $b=4$, which is a contradiction.

By the same way we can get a contradiction for $b=0$.

Thus, $ab\neq0.$

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying both equations, rearranging and factoring gives 
$$ab\left(1+\frac {100}{(a^2+b^2)^2}\right)=10$$
hence $ab\neq 0$.